# Keeping viewmodels up to date with changes in child views

Tags: asp.net-mvc, c#-4.0, razor, razor-declarative-helpers

I have a Razor page with 2 child views inserted into it using Html.DisplayFor():

```
...
     @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.ModelObject.Lines, new { IsEditable = Model.ModelObject.CanEdit })
...
     @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.Payments, new { DocumentId = Model.ModelObject.Id, CanAddPayments = Model.ModelObject.CanAddPayments })
...
```

When I call an action from view 2, I need to be able to get the latest in-memory state of the model (imagine lines were added to the document) before saving the model. Unfortunately it seems that all I can get is the model from when the page was first loaded. I CAN see changes to the viewmodel used in the childview. for example, in the payments child view, I can see payments being updateed, but NOT lines that have been updated in the other view.

Is here some way I can get see one view's changes from the other or make them change the same object?

Comment: I don't understand your question. Are you saying that you are modifying the view model inside a view? If yes then you are probably doing something wrong. The view should only use the view model to display its properties. The manipulation of the view model is something that the controller should take care of.

Comment: Yes, the controller updates the viewmodel. I changed my get action call to a post and it seems to work ok now.